# Integrating differential form question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I was given the following question on an exam this morning and was wondering if my solution was correct? The question was "if $\omega = 2xy\,dx+x^2\,dy$ and $C$ an arbitrary curve from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ calculate $\int_C \omega$. Hint: can you write $\omega$ as $\omega = \,d f$ for some function f? My solution was as follows:
$$f(x,y) = x^2y \Rightarrow \,df =\omega $$
Using Stokes Theorem,
$$\int_C \omega = \int_C \,df = \int_{\partial C} f(x,y)$$
Now my logic was that the boundary of the curve is just the two endpoints. So we are just integrating at two single points and not over any "length" so to speak, then
$$\int_{\partial C} f(x,y)=0$$
That was my rough approach and wasn't sure if how I worked it out was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right answer but for the wrong reason: because the measure on the boundary is $(n-1)$-dimensional, the "$0$-dimensional" measure is just discrete measure (with the normals chosen appropriately, or whatever), and you should have
$$ \int_C df = \int_{\partial C} f = f(0,1)-f(0,0)=0. $$

(Really, Stokes's theorem for a curve is the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (after you choose a parametrisation).)

Answer (score 0):

The curve $C$ is not closed, so it doesn't follow directly from Stokes's theorem that $\int_C \omega = 0$. However, since $\omega = df$ with $f(x,y) = x^2 y$, by the fundamental theorem of line integrals,

$$\int_C \omega = f(0,1) - f(0,0) = 0 - 0 = 0.$$